# Linear Span of a Set W = W itself, and more

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $V$ be a vector space over $F$ and $W\subseteq V$. Prove that:
>
> - $LS(W) = W$ iff $W$ is a subspace of V
> - If $W$ is a subspace of $V$ and $S\subseteq W$ then $LS(S)$ is a subspace of $W $

*Note that* $LS(A)$ denotes the **linear span** of a set of vectors, $A$.

How can this be done?

My approach:

For the first statement, let's start with $W$ being a subspace. Since it's a subspace, it has a basis, say the set of vectors $B(W)$. By definition, $LS(B(W))$ is just $W$, so we've to show that $LS(LS(B(W)) =W$. This is fairly obvious, since finding the linear span of a linear span doesn't give us anything new, so the previous statement is the same as $LS(B(W)) = W$, which we know, is true.

For the other way of the double implication, let's begin with $LS(W) = W$, i.e. $W$ can be given as the linear span of a set (some set, I don't care which?). By definition, the linear span contains the zero vector, and also it's easy to show that if $u,v$ are two vectors in $LS(W)$, then $au+bv$ also belongs to $LS(W)$, for $a,b \in F$.

Is this proof for the first statement alright? Are there better methods to go about it?

Also, for the second bullet point, here's what I've come up with, please tell me if this is alright, and if there are other ways to look at it:

$S \subseteq W$, so the set of vectors in $S$ are part of the vector space $W$. Let $u,v$ be two vectors in $S\cap W$, so $au+bv \in W$ by the definition of a vector space, i.e. all linear combinations lie in the same space. $LS(S)$ is clearly a subspace (since we know it's a subspace, and a subset of $W$) of $W$.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: The linear span of a set is the smallest subspace containing the set.

Comment: That works, except in class, the result you quote had been proved from the results mentioned in the question above - I sense a circular argument. Could you please clear it up?

Comment: Then use that the linear span is the set of all linear combinations, together with the criteria for a subspace: closure under addition and scalar multiplication.